# What is the memcpy equivalent in Forth?

Tags: forth

If I need to copy some memory of a given size, is there a typical Forth word to do this? Something like C's `memcpy` or `memmove`?

Answer (score 3):

## Copying memory

The Forth standard defines `MOVE` in the Core word set, for copying arbitrary memory:

> `MOVE` ( *addr<sub>1</sub>* *addr<sub>2</sub>* *u* -- )
> If *u* is greater than zero, copy the contents of *u* consecutive address units at *addr<sub>1</sub>* to the *u* consecutive address units at *addr<sub>2</sub>*. After `MOVE` completes, the *u* consecutive address units at *addr<sub>2</sub>* contain exactly what the *u* consecutive address units at *addr<sub>1</sub>* contained before the move.

Like `memmove`, `MOVE` allows the source and destination to overlap, as if the copy had happened using an intermediate buffer.

## Propagating strings

The Forth standard also defines `CMOVE` and `CMOVE>` in the String word set:

> `CMOVE` ( *c-addr<sub>1</sub>* *c-addr<sub>2</sub>* *u* -- )
> If *u* is greater than zero, copy *u* consecutive characters from the data space starting at *c-addr<sub>1</sub>* to that starting at *c-addr<sub>2</sub>*, proceeding character-by-character from lower addresses to higher addresses.

> `CMOVE>` ( *c-addr<sub>1</sub>* *c-addr<sub>2</sub>* *u* -- )
> If *u* is greater than zero, copy *u* consecutive characters from the data space starting at *c-addr<sub>1</sub>* to that starting at *c-addr<sub>2</sub>*, proceeding character-by-character from higher addresses to lower addresses.

`CMOVE` and `CMOVE>` copy characters one-by-one, in order, beginning at the start and end of the strings respectively.

`MOVE` is already capable of copying strings safely (using `CHARS` for full compliance with the standard). But `CMOVE` and `CMOVE>` can be used to repeat portions of a string easily, or implement algorithms similar to [LZ77 decompression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78#LZ77). This is known as *propagation*. For example:

```
\ Allocate space for a string, starting with AB
CREATE str  'A' C, 'B' C, 18 CHARS ALLOT

str 2 TYPE  \ prints AB

\ Use CMOVE to propagate AB over rest of string
str  str 2 CHARS +  18  CMOVE

str 20 TYPE  \ prints ABABABABABABABABABAB
```

`CMOVE>` is also known as `<CMOVE` in older Forths.

---

There is a `COPY` word in some Forths for writing a block's contents over another block easily.